# python list object not callable when transforming set to list

Tags: python, list, set

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[2,4,5,6]

c=set(a).intersection(b)  #output is set([2])
```

How do i get output of just 2?

i tried `list(c)` but got this error:

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: what are you expecting?

Comment: You named a list `list`, and now `list(c)` tries to use your list as a function instead of calling the `list` built-in. Don't reuse built-in names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's normal that the output is a `set`, after all the result of an intersection can yield more than one element. If you're interested in a `list` of the elements, this worked for me:

```
c = set(a).intersection(b)
list(c)
=> [2]
```

It's weird that you're getting the error `'list' object is not callable`, that should not happen. Maybe you redefined `list` somewhere? look in your code and see if you did something like this:

```
list = [1, 2, 3]
```

...And that's exactly why it's a bad idea to redefine built-in functions.

Comment: oops yes it was a mistake.

Comment: Gotcha! I knew it :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> a=[1,2,3]
>>> b=[2,4,5,6]
>>> c=set(a).intersection(b) 
>>> print c
set([2])
>>> print type(c)
<type 'set'>
>>> elem = c.pop()
>>> print elem
2
```